# How can I merge GIT into one branch without losing commits?

Tags: git

I make `git push origin master` and get "Everything up-to-date".

`git status`:
HEAD detached from ce8de08
nothing to commit, working directory clean

```
* 0bbe78c 2020-06-12 | some changes (HEAD) [KitaXvost]
* f46d2a6 2020-06-12 | Add errors file [KitaXvost]
* 0221454 2020-06-12 | added styles for displaying messages [KitaXvost]
* de677b1 2020-06-12 | more JQuery used [KitaXvost]
* 39907fd 2020-06-12 | unification of logic forms [KitaXvost]
* f246fb6 2020-06-10 | start new version [KitaXvost]
| *   ce8de08 2020-06-08 | Merge branch 'master' of github.com:KitaXvost/bars (origin/master, master) [root]
| |\  
|/ /  
| * 7bc0239 2020-06-08 | Update config.php [KitaXvost]
* | 18b2712 2020-06-08 | add hidens 2 buttons in refresh function [KitaXvost]
* | 691a03f 2020-06-08 | fixed an error on getting id string in edit.php [KitaXvost]
* | e8c4bec 2020-06-08 | add function refresh in script.js [KitaXvost]
* | 2c5945e 2020-06-08 | delete connect DB and remove render table in index.php [KitaXvost]
* | 962ff92 2020-06-08 | add file refresh.php [KitaXvost]
|/  
* a9b2ad7 2020-06-07 | Add function close for all forms after click submit (shared/master) [KitaXvost]
* 3555a75 2020-06-07 | Create dump DB [KitaXvost]
* 6683779 2020-06-07 | Add delete.php with delete function to delete-form [KitaXvost]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "merge git into one branch"? Merging branches in git doesn't lose commits.

Comment: My question is: what do you want to do? It's not clear to me what the question is. From that output, local master (which is not where you are standing, you are on _detached HEAD_) has been pushed and is right on the same revision as the remote's master.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen and how merge in my situation?

Comment: @eftshift0 how do I send an update to repository?

Answer (score 0):

normally: you set a branch on that revision that you want to push and then push it. It can be a new branch (`git checkout -b new-branch; git push origin new-branch`)... or an existing branch (merging: `git checkout master; git merge -m "Merging" 0bbe78c; git push origin master`, assuming it's that revision what you want to merge into master)... there are many more options, depending on what you want to do, it's not clear from the question what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -2):

Git always require a commit to save your changes at your local branch. Later you can  merge the remote branch.